# Rub a dub dub, Thanks for the grub

Tags: meme

Occasionally I've seen *"itadakimasu"* translated as **Rub a dub dub, Thanks for the grub**.

Most often it's used as an joking example of subbing/dubbing that doesn't stick strictly to the original Japanese script.

Where does it come from though? Was there a show that actually translated it as such?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I doubt it.  This may be more of a language thing than a meme really, since that phrase is commonplace [enough] in America, but *itadakimasu* has entirely different connotations.

Comment: If I'm remembering right, "Rub a dub dub, thanks for the grub" comes from a deliberate trollsub circa the late '00s. Don't remember the details off-hand, though; I'll go internet-spelunking later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[HamtaroWarrior's claims](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/26507/1908) that it doesn't have much to do with anime and that "It just seems to be a way to translate "Itadakimsu"." [sic] miss the point.

There is, in fact, a clear anime-related reason that "rub a dub dub, thanks for the grub" has become emblematic of over-localized translation: the abortive [gg] fansub of *Toradora!!* back in 2008 featured this very line as a translation of Minori's "*itadakimasu*" in episode 4 (around 08:52). This is an absurdly over-the-top translation choice, as any American could attest - Minori is certainly a cheerful and quirky character, but this goes well beyond that.

This was widely hailed as [an innovation in trollsubbing](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EGWwaDhreP8J:https://archive.moe/a/thread/15831373%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) on [gg]'s part, and was one of the factors that cemented their reputation as the leading trollsubbers of their time. I mentioned that the fansub was abortive - indeed, [[gg] stopped subbing *Toradora!!* after episode 4](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=50209#msg1980927), and I guess they decided to go out with a bang (all of the relevant blog posts I'd like to cite appear to have bitrotted out of existence, unfortunately). I emphasize this again - almost surely nobody actually thought that "rub a dub dub, thanks for the grub" was a good choice here. Rather, it was presumably chosen to get a rise out of its viewers (and succeeded quite well at it!).

It is as a *result* of this particular incident that images like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIkD9.jpg) exist (the "gg" column, at least). Likewise, the *Sasami-san@Ganbaranai* image in the question is a deliberate "homage" (if you can call it that) to [gg]'s *Toradora!!* subs of auld.

Comment: Well this is my bad, didn't find those details in 3 hours of net digginng :\

Comment: I could swear Tomo says it in the official English dub of Azumanga Daioh, but am not having luck tracking down a clip.....

Answer (score 0):

Im very sorry that I accidentally tripped over this strand because now I feel obligated to contribute. When I was a pre-medical undergraduate at a small United Methodist liberal arts college in the late 1970's, I competed in intercollegiate athletics. We were obligated to "say grace" before a team meal, so this line was part of our team prayer. The full blessing was:

"Rub a dub dub, Thanks for the grub, Yea God! Amen!"

I hope this contribution rgarging the linguistic history of this irreverent ritual is helpful to this most fascinating discussion.